# Comment traduire « seamless experience » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

> Hopefully we will hire more staff and our technology solutions will grow with us, providing a
> seamless experience for seniors and caregivers.

Comment traduirait-on [*seamless*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/seamless) ici (on hésite vu les choix apparamment variés : *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/seamless), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/seamless/610087), [Wiktionary translation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seamless#Translations), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/seamless)*) ?

Comment: La proposition de Collins *sans heurt* me parait le mieux convenir ici

Comment: @Damien N'hésite pas à contribuer une réponse, ce qui m'intéresse surtout c'est le pourquoi du choix...

Answer (score 2):

Ce qui me frappe, c’est que la meilleure traduction de seamless induit à mon avis une légère adaptation de « experience », plutôt dans le sens de « service ». Cela donnerait: en offrant un service sans faille, par exemple.

Comment: Oui, très bien *service sans faille*. On est trop envahis d'*expériences* calquées de l'anglais. J'éviterais aussi *expérience* dans un texte pour des lecteurs français, mais ici ce sont des Canadiens pour qui expérience ne pose peut-être pas ce problème. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56826599#56826599

Answer (score 1):

Deepl s'en sort bien :

> Il est à espérer que nous engagerons davantage de personnel et que nos solutions technologiques évolueront avec nous, offrant une expérience sans faille aux personnes âgées et aux soignants.

On pourrait remanier la première partie comme ceci :

> Nous espérons pouvoir embaucher plus de personnel et que nos solutions techniques continuerons à progresser avec nous, offrant une expérience sans faille aux personnes âgées et aux soignants.

ou

> offrant une expérience **agréable** aux personnes âgées et aux soignants.

Comment: Si on regarde [_painless_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/painless), vu la morphologie avec -less, pourquoi ne pas opter pour une version sans « sans », de polarité inverse disons, comme « bonne » ou « facilité d'utilisation » ? Pourquoi l'aspect plus neutre est-il privilégié (_homogène_) ?

Comment: Version sans « sans » proposée. *Homogène* était trop neutre, j'en conviens.

Comment: C'est intéressant qu'il n'ait pas encore été proposé, mais je trouve que l'adjectif *fluide* est celui qui correspond le mieux à la situation : "*[...] offrant une expérience fluide aux personnes âgées et aux soignants.*"

Comment: @Reyedy Oui, fluide rend bien *seamless* mais risque peut-être d'être moins rapidement compris qu'agréable.